# Can the with function be used with a GroupBy clause in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: group-by, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Can the with function be used with a GroupBy clause in Laravel Eloquent? Does it serve any purpose if I have specific items to select using the Select Clause?

Following is the query that I currently have

```
Order::with('Campaign')
            ->where('isapproved','=','Y')
            ->groupBy('campaign_id')
            ->orderBy(DB::raw('COUNT(id)','desc'))
            ->get(array(DB::raw('COUNT(id) as totalsales')));
```

The `order` table has a column name `campaign_id` which `belongsTo` the table named `campaigns`. I would like to get the total count of the sales from the order table against each campaign and need to show in the following manner.

```
Total Sales     Campaign
-------------------------
  200            Campaign1
  500            Campaign2
  300            Campaign3
```

Should I have to perform a specific select or can I access the values of the Campaign table from the above query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the referenced column required by the Model specified on the With function is retrieved in the `SELECT` clause, then the `With` function is taken into consideration by the above query. The rectified query will be

```
$groupedSalesCampaign = Order::with('Campaign')
            ->where('isapproved','=','Y')
            ->groupBy('campaign_id')
            ->orderBy(DB::raw('COUNT(id)','desc'))
            ->get(array(DB::raw('COUNT(id) as totalsales'),'campaign_id'));
```

This way the Campaign information can be retrieved using

```
foreach($groupedSalesCampaign as $campaign)
{
      Log::info($campaign->foo->bar);
}
```

Edited.